# Banned from flagging with only 8 declined out of 227

Tags: support, flagging

I have just gotten the notice that I am banned from flagging. I have raised 227 flags and have only had 8 declined. In the last week, 3 of my flags have been declined. One I can understand the answer was subsequently edited and I didn't retract the flag, but the other two were for one sentence non-answers which were already downvoted at the time (and I recall at least one of them had a comment from review, indicating others have flagged them as well, but if so, they're gone).

The [first answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/187977/165253):

> If you use Windows as OS, it's only a Registry setting to change the CPU show ss a different.

This seems like a VLQ answer to me. It is poorly written, does not answer OP's question, and gives no explanations. It's better as a comment (and might not be good even then).

The [second answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/187961/165253):

> You can simply Write KOW insted anything else in the register, so it will show what you have writen.

This answer also seems low-quality. It does not answer the question and frankly makes no sense.

As I have seen *far* better answers proactively deleted by moderators, and have successfully flagged many answers that were higher quality which were subsequently deleted, I am not sure why this resulted in a flag ban. I know that under 75% flag acceptance triggers a ban. I am at 96%.

I have a few questions:

- What triggered the ban, given that I have 96% acceptance?
- When will the ban be lifted, and will it have any lasting repercussions?
- Can I contest the ban?
- What should I do to avoid this in the future? I am already careful with my flags.

Comment: That's interesting because I am at 5 declined out of 117 total (102 helpful)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These sorts of things are automated so I can't give you any useful info beyond the guidance to wait.

Of those though, I'd have to say neither flag should have been raised. Yes, they seem like low value answers, but they are answers, so if you were flagging them for mod attention, I can see why they were rejected. For posts like that, just downvote them.

Comment: Is there a meta discussion on how to determine if an answer should be flagged? I tend to flag based on what I see being deleted proactively, since I don't have a solid guide to follow.

Comment: @forest Not info sec, but still relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Flag oranges and signs with direction for apples. Downvote rotten apples, but don't flag them.

Comment: @Anders Ah I see the problem. I was going more by https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226142/384528

Comment: @forest That answer also makes a very good point... Clearly this is more complicated when it comes to answers than it is for apples.